# How should I set up a development environment with Docker for WordPress themes?

Tags: wordpress, docker

Little disclaimer before I start: I am a Docker newbie.

My question is mostly stated as above, with a little bit more to my requirements:

- I want to have a "full" development experience. That is, I want to be able to use VS Code, WebStorm, etc. to do development with full-featured guesser and code intelligence. **This is what my current setup is lacking.**
- I want to have a `docker-compose.yml` that I can commit into my source repository and not worry about "how it will run" on multiple platforms. I *think* what I have below accomplishes that, but I am very open to criticism.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  wp:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 48080:80
    links:
      - db:mysql
    volumes:
      - themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

volumes:
  themes:
```

Any tips for moving forward?

Answer (score 1):

The theme volume did not work on my machine. If I run `docker-compose up` I get the following error:
[image]
This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  wp:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 48080:80
    links:
      - db:mysql
    volumes:
      - ./themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Everything else looks quite good, only improvement for now would be hosting your WordPress on your local file system:

That would give you the possibility to debug WordPress easily and you have full control over the stack.

**Downside:** User permission can be a problem with Docker. Normally every process inside the container will be executed as root. If WordPress writes a file it has root permissions even on you local file system.

Comment: So in setting up to use the whole WP stack as the volume (such as `./wp:/var/www/html` instead of themes), what am I gaining by using the WordPress image instead of just using the PHP image?

Comment: I am sorry, of course you should use the php image than. ;) (I forgot to metion it)